# Add a setting to allow you to see all comments, not just the top 5

Tags: feature-request, comments

Currently when a SO post has more than some 5 or 6 comments the rest of them are hidden and you have to click a link to show them all. It would be nice if there was an option that all the comments are shown all the time. (Or even better - that you could specify the hiding threshold).

Comment: Just waste your days on Meta, where you can see 15 comments by default before you have to click the link to show more.

Comment: Naah, SO is way more fun! XD

Comment: Who said anything about having fun here?

Comment: Somewhat related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24490/can-we-get-an-indication-comments-are-hidden-between-the-comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would have no effect on the vast majority of posts (those that have five or fewer comments, and those that you just don't care about reading comments of). It would be actively bad for posts that have many comments you don't care about, because it would increase scrolling.

For those few posts where it *would* help you, that's adding a lot of complexity and spending a lot of dev time to save a few "show all comments" clicks. Comments are designed to be second-class content, after all.

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't agree more. There would be other things I'd like settings for, such as the javascript that makes typing in comments unbearably slow (so slow that letters get misplaced and I often have to wait 4 seconds before I can type on, and that is not even when the temp save is done, which is even worse). If this could be done, great! But I suppose it might be a lot of work to implement.