# Prevent the "conversation moved to chat" comment from being hidden

Tags: feature-request, comments, chat

Would it be possible to prevent the "conversation moved to chat" comment that's left when moderators [move a lengthy comment chain to chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237976/260382) from being hidden?

The message that's left when moderators move comments says:

> Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been moved to chat.

Which links to the chatroom and is usually a good reminder to people that they should be using comments for their intended purpose. However what usually happens, especially on HNQ questions, is that posts continue to attract chatty comments. Often those comments attract some upvotes. Before long enough comments are left that **this "moved to chat" comment [will be hidden](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139776/what-determines-the-number-of-comments-that-are-displayed)** as they rarely get many upvotes.

As a moderator all I'm left with then is simply nuking all those comments. I sometimes edit the automated message to include formatting and additional explanation in the hope of making it more visible and attracting upvotes but the problem of this message dropping off the default display remains. When I leave existing useful comments in place the "moved to chat" comment might never even be shown by default.

To be effective it seems like **this automated comment should be prevented from being hidden**.

As this might require changes to the way comments or the hiding algorithm work, one quick fix would be to auto-apply upvote(s) to the comment from the community user. If upvotes need to be tied to single users, an additional automatic upvote from the moderator could get it to +2 though I imagine that could break things in other fun ways.

Comment: Wouldnt the solution be to apply a comment lock, or is that staff only?

Comment: @Luuklag The "using a bazooka to swat a fly" analogy comes to mind then. :) It will prevent useful comments from coming in as well and especially on the site I moderate ([workplace.se]) clarification is often needed from the OP. Those are also the type of  comments I usually leave up (undelete) and with a lock the OP would be prevented from answering those as well.

Comment: I agree to some extent Llienthal. It would prevent useful comments for clarification, but it doesn't prevent OP from adding additional information. Seeing that that information should be incorporated into the question itself.

Comment: So... y'all have special rules for collapsing comments which means that they get collapsed much more severely than anywhere else on the network - and I'm not sure that can be overridden because it's paired with the too many answers warning for users. I don't disagree with your ask but I thought I'd point out that TWP (and IPS) is a bit different.

Comment: Whenever I see a "moved to chat" comment I upvote it, but I agree that not many other people do that (at least, not on the sites I frequent). So IMHO it would be great if such comments were impervious to being hidden.

Comment: @Catija Indeed, Workplace has its own set of rules. ;) Those are described on the linked meta question on how comments are hidden. I must admit I don't know how (much less) prevalent this scenario is on other sites. Our stricter comment hiding no doubt magnifies this but I assumed that most of the less technical sites run into this as well so I didn't want to narrow this down to just Workplace. (Off-topic, but I didn't find any references to IPS handling comments differently as well.)

Comment: I expect this only really comes up on HNQ questions given their higher comment traffic, but if this is only really an issue on Workplace then we certainly don't need site-wide changes. We could find a bot-based fix similar to how Smoke Detector works if we were truly desperate. ;)