# When there are "More comments," often the thread is lost

Tags: feature-request, comments

When not all comments are shown, often only the start of the discussion and the end is seen, with some comments in the middle cut out. Often this makes the discussion incomprehensible. Please mark the place where comments are elided.

Comment: The `more comments` link is quite prominent. Why not just click it?

Comment: What is the difference between your feature request and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24490/can-we-get-an-indication-comments-are-hidden-between-the-comments?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Particularly on meta, where more comments are shown on posts, the indication that there are hidden comments could be well below the bottom of the current screen.  On non-meta sites it can still happen, although it's somewhat less likely.

Comment: @Simon, none whatsoever. Sorry about that.