# Why are comments hidden in a non-linear manner?

Tags: support, comments

I have noticed that comments are expanded in a different way when I click "**see more comments**". For example, if an answer has 10 comments, on loading the page it shows only limited comments with a bottom view "**View 4 more comments"**. But the comments are getting expanded in a non-linear manner as the hidden comments are being shown between the existing comments when I click **"View 4 more comments"**. Is there any specific reason for that or is it designed in that manner?

Comment: That's because the comments that appear when you click 'view x more comments' have less votes than the ones which you first see.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24490/282094 - It's not a Bug, nor will it be fixed. It's also agreed that it's annoying. --- Notice the [name of the user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/132547/move-more-comments-link-to-top), 10 years ago changed their name to protest. They were 1st!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365/282094), and [numbers of answers needed to cause collapsing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86893/282094).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When there are many comments, only part of the comments are visible.

In attempt to show the most relevant comments, the sort is made by the comment score, then they take X top comments, where X is defined per site. (Maybe it's explained somewhere, but it's not the topic here.)

So, for example, when there are 8 comments total, with scores of 3, 6, 1, 0, 0, 7, 9, and 0, and the site showing only three comments, those with score 6, 7, and 9 will be visible by default. When expanded, the sort is only by date, so those comments with top score will "jump" into place.

Comment: "the sort is made by the comment score" - they are _filtered_ by the "comment score", but they are never actually _sorted_ by it - they still remain in chronological order.